# iOS: How to transform a type in a string in the Constants.h?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsstring, constants

I have a piece of code that works well with a class declaration and a string declaration, but I would like to save code by knowing the way to transform a class name declaration in a string. Here is an example that works:

```
#define FORM_TO_USE             RegistrationForm_Renault_Sport
#define FORM_TO_USE_SWIFT       @"RegistrationForm_Renault_Sport"
```

But I want something more generic, for example:

```
#define FORM_TO_USE             RegistrationForm_Renault_Sport
#define FORM_TO_USE_SWIFT       [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",FORM_TO_USE]
```

or

```
#define FORM_TO_USE             RegistrationForm_Renault_Sport
#define FORM_TO_USE_SWIFT       String(FORM_TO_USE)
```

But this two last examples doesn't work.

My goal is to use this in swift:

```
    let anyobjectype : AnyObject.Type = NSClassFromString(FORM_TO_USE_SWIFT)!
    let nsobjectype : NSObject.Type = anyobjectype as! NSObject.Type
    let fieldsObjC: AnyObject = nsobjectype.init()
```

ERROR MESSAGE:
[image]
Any ideas?

Comment: what is RegistrationForm_Renault_Sport?

Comment: This is a class name. I cannot use it directly with the swift, but if I use in the swift, the NSClassFromString(FORM_TO_USE_SWIFT) with a string inside, it works.

Comment: @ΩlostA where do you put these `#define` lines? Are they in a Objective-C file?

Comment: @trungduc yep exactly, it is in my Constants.h objective c file

Comment: Actually, I don't know why you need to define string in objective-c and use it in swift. Can you explain? Maybe I can help you

Comment: @trungduc Because 80% of my code is in objective C and I have to do the transition to swift, but it is going to take lots of time. I don't want to have two code similar in two differents side, specially with my big constant.h file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is creating an Objective-C class method for each of the `#define` macros — that returned the macro value. For example.

**Constants.h**

```
#define FORM_TO_USE             RegistrationForm_Renault_Sport
#define FORM_TO_USE_SWIFT       [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",FORM_TO_USE]

@interface Constants : NSObject

+ (NSString *)formToUseSwift;

@end
```

**Constants.m**

```
@implementation Constants

+ (NSString *)formToUseSwift {
  return FORM_TO_USE_SWIFT;
}

@end
```

**Swift file**

```
let anyobjectype : AnyObject.Type = NSClassFromString(Constants.formToUseSwift())!
let nsobjectype : NSObject.Type = anyobjectype as! NSObject.Type
let fieldsObjC: AnyObject = nsobjectype.init()
```

In my opinion, it's only possible way to avoid having two code similar in two differents side.

**Sample**

https://github.com/trungducc/stackoverflow/tree/swift-constant-from-objective-c

Comment: @ trungduc I have a problem, an error message "Use of undeclared identifier RegistrationForm_Renault_Sport" => on that return FORM_TO_USE_SWIFT;

Comment: Please edit your question with related error code. I will help you.

Comment: Sorry but what is `RegistrationForm_Renault_Sport` in your code?

Comment: It is the name of a Class. I use it in my code that way : FORM_TO_USE* form = ...

Comment: Let try `#define FORM_TO_USE             @"RegistrationForm_Renault_Sport"`

Comment: The problem is that I could not use as I use it in my code that way : FORM_TO_USE* form = [FORM_TO_USE new]; ...

Comment: It got it. Try again `#define FORM_TO_USE_SWIFT       NSStringFromClass(FORM_TO_USE.class)`

Comment: I will check on my side, thank you very much for the time spent with me :D

Comment: Welcome ;). Feel free to ask me if you need my help.